# Has anybody gotten Vega-Lite to work in Angular 5?

Tags: vega, vega-lite

Following the straight up JS instructions but within TypeScript, I get the following error:

```
Signal bind element not found: null
```

in the logger component.

I'm using all the latest versions of vega, vega-lite, and vega-embed

It seems that vega-embed is the only way to use vega-lite?

Comment: Please update your question to show some code.  There is no way for us to tell what is going on if we don't see it.

Comment: Please see the thread [here](https://github.com/vega/vega-embed/issues/64).  Thank you.

Comment: Vega-Lite works with Angular 5 - my title should have been 'Has anybody gotten Vega-Embed to work in Angular 5?'  It is Vega-Embed that produced the error for me.